# Print in PDF how to make save dialog not appear?

Tags: c#, pdf

My code:

```
string args = @"/h /n /t """ + f + @""" ";
var adobeprocess = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"AcroRd32.exe", args);
var hasExited = adobeprocess.WaitForExit(wait);

if (!hasExited)
{
    adobeprocess.CloseMainWindow();
    adobeprocess.Kill();
}
```

When the pdf is closed a save dialog appears, but I don't want that to appear.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18678114/printing-pdfs-without-opening-the-print-dialogbox

Comment: @CodeCaster I don't see the solution in that question

Comment: There is no solution, the answer is that it isn't possible. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508763/c-sharp-prevent-adobe-reader-window-from-coming-up-when-trying-to-print-a-docume

Comment: @CodeCaster Acctually the solution was not to have CutePdf Writer as standard printer.