# Qt, PDF viewer, and jumping to specific pages

Tags: qt, pdf

I've spent a couple of days searching the bowels of the internet to find out the answer to my question, so since I can't find the answer I'm throwing it out to the masses...

Within my Qt application I'm able to open a PDF using the OS default viewer thru the following command:

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("file:////C:help.pdf", QUrl::TolerantMode));
```

This works fine because all I'm wanting to do is display a help file to a user, but when I try to add a "#page=20" parameter to my URL, the document still only opens to the first page, not page 20.  If I cut and paste the command into a browser it jumps correctly.

So -- my questions are:

1. Would poppler or another viewing tool allow me to jump to a page?
2. Is there another way with Qt to jump to a page? Or maybe another command to open the file instead of with QDesktopServices?

edit:  I tried with QProcess and that doesn't jump to the page either -- not that I expected it to...

Comment: Your URL looks strange. Do you mean: `"file://C:/help.pdf"`?

Comment: Actually, what I did was eliminate my username from the link and created a typo -- you are correct, sorry!

Answer (score 4):

Use `QProcess` with one of the answers from [Adobe Reader Command Line Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619158/adobe-reader-command-line-reference) :

```
<path to Adobe Reader> /A "page=100" "<Path To PDF file>"
```

Comment: Hmmm, I'll have to give this a shot later (when I get home from my day job).  I'd already successfully launched it with QProcess w/out the page numbers but if I can figure out a way to embed those options within the arguments to QProcess maybe that'll do it!

Comment: Note that while this *is* a solution, it isn't portable at all neither respecting the operating system nor the PDF viewer.

Comment: Yep, already considered that...I used QProcess for something else in my app and already had to address it -- thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes.  `evince`, for example, takes option `--page-index` which you can set page number
2. No.  `QDesktopServices::openUrl()` ends up calling one of helper commands, such as `xdg-open` or `kfmclient`, without any arguments.

Of cause, you can always use [libpoppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/) in your app to open your PDFs. [`Poppler::Document::page()`](http://people.freedesktop.org/~aacid/docs/qt4/classPoppler_1_1Document.html#a2b95d382dbeb371ff149a35be560e6b0) is your friend.

Comment: that explains why   QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("file://C:/help.pdf#page=20")); drops the #page=20 parameter when I associated the test.pdf file Chrome instead of Reader -- thanks for that input...

Comment: If I can't get QProcess to work (which seems like a faster way of getting to a solution since I'm almost there), then I'll try your two ideas -- thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution I was able to work out was to convert my PDF to HTML, create a QWebView, and display the HTML there.  I then added an ID attribute to the HTML doc, and when I tacked that ID to my URL it loaded into the widget at the location of the attribute...

scott