# Printing a PDF file

Tags: java, pdf, printing, swt

In my application, I am taking selected user data and creating a PDF file.  The PDF file is saved on their local machine. I have a table in my Dialog displaying the PDF filename and location.

I am wanting to add a button to the bottom of the table.  The button will print the selected PDF file name to a local printer.  I really don't need to view the PDF File.  I just want to be able to select a local printer and print the PDF File.

With the button click,

1. I can get the file name and location from the selected table cell.
2. I can get local printers using PrintDialog

I do not know where to go from here.

Do I need a special open source like PdfRenderer?
Do I have to get the file back in to my Application or is it possible to print from its location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need a PDF you should consider printing directly. [Paperclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/paperclips/paperclips.php) from Nebula can help you. Additionally if you assume that Adobe Acrobat is used, you can start Acrobat Reader with a special flag from command-line that opens directly the print-dialog, see [Adobe Reader Command Line Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619158/adobe-reader-command-line-reference)

Comment: Can Paperclipse actually just print out a existing PDF file?

Comment: No, this is not possible. You have to layout the document you want to print extra the "paperclipse-way"...