# PCL Format generation from pdf in java

Tags: java, pdf, jasper-reports, printer-control-language

I want to export jasperreport report in pcl format , but i didn't find a way to do it , so i generated in pdf .

I want to create a class that convert this pdf to PCL5 format. So please can you give me a sarting point and suggetions .

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1):

I don't there are any products left that will export any level of PCL.  Print to a PCL driver, but not directly export it.

You can use any PCL5 driver with Acrobat to print to FILE:  And, there are many products that will batch print PDF's.

However, a lot depends on what you expect to do with the PCL5?  And, why?

Bob Pooley
bp@pagetech.com

Comment: You could print to the device via the command line to a PCL 5 printer using Acrobat: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619158/adobe-reader-command-line-reference