# VB.NET printing several ,pdf-files in background to specified printer

Tags: vb.net, pdf, printing, itext

I need to print several PDF-documents to a specific network printer. They have to be in a specific order. This should preferably go on in the background. I have created a VB.NET program that reads the names of the PDF documents in correct order from an Excel sheet and that works fine, but my problem is getting them printed out. Someone suggested the iTextSharp library, but I cannot find any documentation that explains how to open a .pdf-file, add pdf's and then print.

Please help!

Brgds
IVer in Oslo

Answer (score 2):

iTextSharp cannot print PDF files. You can use Adobe Reader to print the files, see this question for more details: [Adobe Reader Command Line Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619158/adobe-reader-command-line-reference), or you can use a 3rd party library for printing PDF files, but this solution might cost money.