# c# printing a pdf landscape without resorting to 3rd party?

Tags: c#, pdf, landscape

I'm trying to simply print a pdf file in landscape in C# code.  Is it simply possible to do without 3rd party software perhaps through a system method?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this without 3rd party software, Windows does not have built in printing capabilities. 
If you do not want to use a paid .NET library to integrate printing in your application, you can use Adobe Reader to print the PDF files from command line, see more details here: [Adobe Reader Command Line Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619158/adobe-reader-command-line-reference)