# Send a File Directly for Printing

Tags: php, .net, jsp, printing

I have an app to make and the basic idea is that a client sits on the master computer whilst a server on the other. You drag and drop a file from one of the child computers, enter the number of copies and send it. (VIA TCP) it is received on the other end and printed.

The problem I am facing is that HOW TO send the FILE (.docx, .pdf, .png, .pptx, etc. ANY FORMAT) for printing.

I can use .NET (ANY), JSP and PHP :)

Comment: You will need to start the respective application on the server with arguments to print the document (or use DDE). The problem is that to do this, you need to have all the applications the user should be able to print documents from installed on the server.

Comment: Can you please expand?

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619158/adobe-reader-command-line-reference) question for an answer on how to automate printing documents using acrobat reader. Basically, you would upload the file to the server and then call the respective acrobat reader command to print the document on a specified printer. To do the same in word, it's a bit more complex, because you'll have to use DDE (dynamic data exchange). Consult the MSDN for further information, I haven't been using it before.