# Open a specific page in a PDF file c#

Tags: c#, pdf, page-numbering

I open a pdf file when my form is loaded with the following code:

```
Process process = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
startInfo.FileName = @"F:\STAGE\test.pdf";
process.Start();
```

This works fine but now I want to open a specific page. For example page number 5 of the document test.pdf? Does any one have an idea? Tried some stuff but dind't work!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/A \"page=n\" \"F:\\STAGE\\test.pdf"";
```

changing `n` to the page number you want

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this : http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/PDFOpenParameters.pdf

It explain what arguments Adobe Reader can receive.

And it has a Page argument.

Your code must be :

```
Process process = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
startInfo.Arguments = "/A \"page=N\"";
startInfo.FileName = @"F:\STAGE\test.pdf";
process.Start();
```

Where N is your page number.

Comment: The program still opens on page 1. Even though I replaced N for 5

Answer (score 0):

call it like what was suggested here: [Adobe Reader Command Line Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619158/adobe-reader-command-line-reference)

So it would be:

```
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.FileName = "EXE_PATH\\AcroRd32.exe";
    startInfo.Arguments = "/A \"page=PAGE_NUM\" \"FILE_PATH\"";
    Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code.

```
  Process myProcess = new Process();
  myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe";
  myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/A \"page={pagenum}\" \"c:\\Classic\\Manual\\DocumentationManual.pdf\"";
  myProcess.Start();
```

please change the path of AcroRd32.exe as per your directory.

Thanks

Comment: Does this extract a specific page from the PDF? What if you wanted to extract different pages that are not sequential?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. 
Note: you must have acrobat reader installed in your pc before you can use axAcroPDF .

```
            int n = 5; //page number
            string filePath = "F:\STAGE\test.pdf";

            axAcroPDF1.LoadFile(filePath);
            axAcroPDF1.setCurrentPage(n);
```