# print pdf file via printer device in qt

Tags: c++, qt, pdf, printing, network-printers

i am new C++ QT programmer,i want to print multi pdf files via my printer device(or network printer),i searched and find this tutorial:
[Qt Handling PDF file](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Handling_PDF)
but i can't compile MuPDF and Poppler and use these third-party libs in my application.my pdf file encrypted too and must print file from memory.
is way to print pdf file via my printer device?

Comment: Is it forbidden to use any third party program ? You may invoke ghostscript which understands PDF and supports a lot of output languages.

Comment: yes,my boss forbidden me to use third-library,can i print ghostscript file via printer device directly?can i convert my pdf file to ghostscript file easyly?

Comment: windows platform(windows xp,7)

Comment: With ghostscript you would still have to figure out which printer type to serve. I think the most simpole approach would be to invoke acrobat reader see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619158/adobe-reader-command-line-reference) a specially the /t option.

Comment: in realy my pdf is encrypted and must not save in pdf file on disk, for this reason i can't using command line acrobat reader.

Comment: how can i use ghostscript in QT?

Comment: Well if you're not allowed to save on disk my guess is that ghostscript won't help you either. The part with the encryption is actually a quite substantial. Ghostscript would just be a PDF translator which generates printer specific output which you might simply copy to the printer of your choosing.

Comment: so,what can i do?any idea?

Comment: don't know if it's possible to pipe a pdf stream into into acrobat reader from your aplication.

Answer (score 2):

Hello you can use something like this.

```
QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
printer.setOrientation(QPrinter::Portrait);
QPrintDialog dlg(&printer, this);
dlg.setWindowTitle("Print");

if (dlg.exec() == QDialog::Accepted)
{
    QWidget* widget = new QWidget(his); // this widget is your pdf widget
    QPixmap printPixmap(widget->width(),widget->height());
    widget->render(&printPixmap,QPoint(),QRegion(0,0,widget->width(),widget->height()));
    QPainter painterPixmap(&printer);
    painterPixmap.scale(4,4);
    painterPixmap.drawPixmap(printer.pageRect().topLeft(), printPixmap, printPixmap.rect());
}
```

Comment: i want to send pdf file to printer device(example network printer), i dont want to print my widget,

Comment: OK, if you can render the file on the widget, than you can print like this.

Comment: i cant use mupdf and poppler for render pdf(realy i couldent compile this library for qt5),any render library or way exiss??