# 8.1 Universal App C# : how open pdf file in specific page

Tags: c#, pdf, win-universal-app

I develop a windows universal app (8.1) in C# and i want to open a local pdf file at a specific page with using Adobe Pdf Reader (not rendering pdf in my application).

Someone has already do that ? After some hours of search it seems to be impossible :(

Answer (score 0):

According to [this PDF](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf), found through [Adobe Reader Command Line Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619158/adobe-reader-command-line-reference), it's the command line

```
Acrobat.exe /A "page=123" "C:\example.pdf"
```

But that's for the Desktop executable. It may work for mobile as well.

Comment: In browsers, you can append ?page=N to the Uri, maybe this also works when invoking the mobile reader using a launch Uri instead of a direct StorageFile Reference...

Comment: It seems to be impossible to launch exe with args in Windows Store Application too :(

Answer (score -1):

try this

Option 1 to read in app.
Use third party PDF reader controls.
[enter link description here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/paulwhit/archive/2013/02/15/pdf-view-components-for-windows-store-apps-winrt-xaml-c.aspx)

Option 2: to open pdf in pdf reader app.

```
  var StorageFile= get you pdf here...;

  await Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(StorageFile);
```

Comment: OP explicitly said _"at a specific page"_. Also "try this" isn't a good answer, explain what that code does and how you think it will solve OP's problem.