# AcroRd32.exe - Print specific pdf page with command line not working

Tags: pdf, command-line, printing, acrobat

I have a **pdf** file which has **10 pages**.

I am trying to **print** only page **number 5** from this **pdf file** with **command line** using **AcroRd32.exe**.

But its not working.

I am running following **command** using **command prompt**:

```
AcroRd32.exe /a "page=1"; /n/t "C:\Users\maninder\Desktop\sunnypatial.pdf" "Brother DCP-1600 series" "Brother DCP-1600"
```

Please suggest, how can i resolve this issue.

Comment: did you try with a capital A?
see this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619158/adobe-reader-command-line-reference

Comment: @Ereli: Yes, i tried capital A

Comment: I'm pretty certain that would just open to that page, not print just that page. From what I can tell this isn't possible.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38698411/print-a-specific-pdf-page-using-command-line#:~:text=No.,displays%20the%20Print%20dialog%20box.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print a specific PDF page using command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38698411/print-a-specific-pdf-page-using-command-line)