# Print Specific Pages of PDF via Batch

Tags: batch-file, pdf, printing, adobe

I am scripting printing PDF's via simple `print D:\\server\printer file.pdf` command and it works, but I'd like to print only the first `X` pages in some instances or the last page etc.

Is there a way to specify pages? Perhaps I need to use Adobes executable to print and/or just manually split files myself ahead of time (The files are generally static "onboarding" files).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found no way to specify pages when printing, but thankfully my print jobs are mostly static. There is likely a way to script splitting files via "Microsoft Print to PDF" but I did that manually and printed the pages I wanted to a new PDF.

Ironically, the `print` command didn't work with PDF's generated via this method, so I switched to printing via `AcroRd32.exe`

Update: I figured it out using VBS, posted on this question as it has most views and flagged this and another as dups.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38698411/print-a-specific-pdf-page-using-command-line#:~:text=No.,displays%20the%20Print%20dialog%20box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38698411/print-a-specific-pdf-page-using-command-line#:%7E:text=No.,displays%20the%20Print%20dialog%20box)

[Adobe Reader Command Line Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619158/adobe-reader-command-line-reference)

Answer (score 1):

Win2PDF has a command line that can print a range of documents:

```
win2pdfd.exe printpdf "sourcefile" printername startpage endpage
```

More information is at:
https://www.win2pdf.com/doc/command-line-print-pdf.html

Comment: Installing 3rd party software is a no go for me, but the answer may help others. +1 thanks!