# How to provide parameters while opening a pdf in CMD?

Tags: windows, cmd, adobe, acrobat

Is there a way to give page number (as parameter) to open a pdf using the given command in CMD, start ""/max "F:\filename.pdf". Or there is a different way? What are the other parameters that can be provided?

Comment: check there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619158/adobe-reader-command-line-reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Google is your friend**.

https://www.google.com.au/search?q=acrobat+viewer+command+line

Leads to Adobe's documentation

http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf

> When opening a PDF document from a command shell, you can pass the parameters to the open command using the /A switch with the following syntax:
>
> `<Acrobat path> /A "<parameter>=<value>" "<PDF path>"`
>
> For example:
>
> `Acrobat.exe /A "zoom=1000" "C:\example.pdf"`

Then later

> `page=pagenum` Specifies a numbered page in the document, using an integer value. The document’s first page has a pagenum value of 1.

Comment: Is there something similar for MS Word Files? I tried to google stuff, but was not able to find something concrete.