# Opening PDF to a specific page

Tags: java, pdf

I'm trying to open a PDF file with Java and jump to a specific page.
Here is my code to open a PDF file:

```
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
  try {
    File file = new File("file.pdf");
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
  } catch (IOException ex) {
    System.err.println('error:' + ex);
  }
}
```

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Did you check if using open parameters helps: https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf (I'm posting this as a comment, not as an answer because I didn't check myself. However, the link may be helpful.)

Comment: I think pdf files should be associated with one of the programs in your PC which could be used for opening these files

Comment: Otherwise you could use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + file);`. It is not so pretty but it should do what you need

Comment: Yes I think I may be helpful for Adobe Acrobat Reader, but I would like it to work on all PDF reader (well, not all but at least Chrome and Firefox too)

Comment: Probably you have to run the reader with an argument like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619158/adobe-reader-command-line-reference

Comment: I'm gonna try @Dumbo, thank you!

Comment: Well, I didn't see this psot @PeterMmm, thank you!

Comment: I think you shouldn't use Adobe Reader, because not all of the computer may have it installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you are using specific program to open PDF it is possible to use appropriate command line arguments.
E.g. if you are using *Acrobat Reader* you can do so:

`AcroRd32.exe /A "page=<PAGE_NUMBER>" <PATH_TO_PDF>`

In Java it might look something like this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("AcroRd32.exe /A \"page=10\" C:/test.pdf");
```

Of course `AcroRd32.exe` should be in the PATH in this case, otherwise you will need to provide full path to the program.