# Printing from PHP to local printer

Tags: php, windows, printing, wampserver, shell-exec

Tring to print PDF direct from PHP

```
shell_exec('"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Adobe\\Acrobat Reader DC\\Reader\\AcroRd32.exe" /t /n "c:\\wamp\\www\\test.pdf" "Zebra ZC300 Network Card Printer"');
```

Adobe reader is starting (look in task menager) but it is doing nothing.
from CMD

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" /t /n "c:\wamp\www\test.pdf" "Zebra ZC300 Network Card Printer"
```

works well.

**The same issue when I am tring PDFtoPrinter.exe its working from CMD but when php send command PDFtoPrinter freeze**

Comment: try to change the backslashes to forward slashes,  you can use both for windows path and sometime they solved some issues for me.

Comment: @Eineki the same issue

Comment: apart the potential issue spotted by @KJ, you may try to add the params `/o /h /s` as stated in comments to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619158/adobe-reader-command-line-reference